# How to repeat GIF Image animation using jquery?

Tags: jquery, gif

I am using Gif image for animation but animation plays just one time. How can I make it play continuously using jquery?

Comment: replace it when finished.

Comment: I don't want to use settimeout or interval. How to find that animation ends?

Comment: that is secondary question. what have you tried to solve it? i don't think there is anything in javascript which can calculate the gif animation time.

Comment: You can't; either measure the time it normally takes and then reload the image, or edit the gif to make it repeat. The latter will probably be more fluent (never too late, never too soon).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions :)